# Change textview in a Cardview in a Recicler View using given position

Tags: android-studio

I want to change a TextView inside a CardView in a RecyclerView.

When user clicks on one item, I want to change a text in another cardview item.

How do I call to change a specific CardView position.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Custom_Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {



        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(view -> {

           holder.tv_text.setText("example");  (CHANGE ANOTHER POSITION ITEM HERE)

(HOW TO DEFINE CERTAIN POSITION TO CHANGE??)
        }


}
```

Comment: You need to change the underlying data structure and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.

Comment: how do I call notifyDataSetChanged  from inside the Custom_Adapter class?

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` is a method on the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()